# PHP: Change colour of html elements depending on the open status of shop

Tags: php, css

I have a query which prints out shops and their information, what i am trying to do is change the colour of the shops information, depending on if the shop is open or not. so for example display red if open and grey if shut.

I have created the css and html already.
What my problem is, is that according to the colour change the shop seems to open and shut together, even if one is open and the other is closed.

I was using a if statement which i know works, as the same if statement(s) display if the shop is open, closed or will open soon and it does that perfectly. However in another script.

In order to resolve the issue i added a for statement, as i logically thought if i could count the number of shops then loop through the script that is meant to change the colour, depending on the number of shops it would work but no luck.

At the moment 1 shop is closed and the other is open. The styles for a open shop is being displayed for both shops.

```
  for ($x = 0; $x <= $count_rw ; $x++) {
//Open later
    if ($time < $st_time) {


        //print("$output"); 
        $output = $output . '<div id="products_view">' .
                '<div id="products_box">' .
                '<div id="products">' .
                '<table>' .
                '<tr class="float">' .
                ' <td class="float"><h3 id="rest_name">' . $rest_name . '</h3> </td>' .
                '<td class="float"><p class="title"> Price</p></td>' .
                '<td class="avg"><p class="title">Avg Delivery</p></td>' .
                '<td><p class="title">Cost</p></td>' .
                '<td> ' . opening_time($rest_id) . ' </td>' .
                '<td id="button" rowspan="2"><a href="product_page.php?rest_id=' . $rest_id . '&Postcode=' . $searchq . '"><button id="feed">Pre-order</button></a></td>' .
                '</tr>' .
                '</table>' .
                '</div>' .
                '</div>';
        $i++;

        //open
    } elseif($time >= $st_time && $cl_time >= $time) {
    //}elseif(($st_time < $time)&&($time<$cl_time)){

        $x = 1;
        $output = $output . '<div id="products_view">' .
                '<div id="products_box">' .
                '<div id="products">' .
                '<table>' .
                '<tr class="float">' .
                ' <td class="float"><h3 id="rest_name">' . $rest_name . '</h3> </td>' .
                '<td class="float"><p class="title"> Price</p></td>' .
                '<td class="avg"><p class="title">Avg Delivery</p></td>' .
                '<td><p class="title">Cost</p></td>' .
                '<td> ' . opening_time($rest_id) . ' </td>' .
                '<td id="button" rowspan="2"><a href="product_page.php?rest_id=' . $rest_id . '&Postcode=' . $searchq . '"><button id="feed">Feed Me!</button></a></td>' .
                '</tr>' .
                '</table>' .
                '</div>' .
                '</div>';
        $x++;
  //closed
    } else {
        $output = $output . '<div id="products_view">' .
                '<div id="grey">' .
                '<div id="products">' .
                '<table>' .
                '<tr class="float">' .
                ' <td class="float"><h3 id="rest_name_grey">' . $rest_name . '</h3> </td>' .
                '<td class="float"><p class="title"> Price</p></td>' .
                '<td class="avg"><p class="title">Avg Delivery</p></td>' .
                '<td><p class="title">Cost</p></td>' .
                '<td> ' . opening_time($rest_id) . ' </td>' .
                '<td id="button_grey" rowspan="2"><a href="product_page.php?rest_id=' . $rest_id . '&Postcode=' . $searchq . '"><button id="feed_grey">Closed</button></a></td>' .
                '</tr>' .
                '</table>' .
                '</div>' .
                '</div>';
```

**Variables**

$count-rw : is defined in a count query

$st_time and $cl_time are defined in separate query.start and closing time.

$time is the current time

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what $time, $st_time, $cl_time all are. But why not add a class and remove a class when they are closed/open rather that output a whole block of html? I would output it all, then go back after it's all outputted then check to see if it is closed/open, THEN add the appropriate classes.

Comment: @Radmation sorry i forgot to add that extra info. $time is the current time and $st_time and $cl_time are the start and close them called from the db for the shop. oh i didn't even think of that

Comment: @Radmation but my issue is getting them to change colour separately

Comment: I suspect if you inspect element they both either have the `div="grey"` or the both lack it. Meaning that your logic is not working correctly. To change one of the div's but not the others you can loop through them (once they are added to the DOM) and check the times -> if it is closed then `$(this).addClass("yourClosedClass");` Maybe something like that.

Comment: Also why not create a function that outputs the HTML for you and pass in a parameter - closed/open that returns the necessary output. That would clean your code up, and make debugging easier. Just a thought.

Comment: Also what is the difference between the first 2 statements? The if and else if? They look the same to me. I can see the else has the different div with an id of gray. Also does an id make sense?? I am assuming you have many closed shops, and an id is meant to be for one unique element? Classes are meant to be shared.

Comment: `if($time < $st_time)` translates to if the current time is less that the stores open time =  CLOSED -  need gray here      

`elseif($time >= $st_time && $cl_time >= $time)` translates to if the current time is greater than the opening time and the stores close time is greater or equal to the current time = OPEN - no gray needed


Those look right to me!! *I think though the first statement needs to have the gray piece added.*

Comment: @Radmation the first 2 if statements are similar one shows it is open today, the other shows its open now, and the last one is grey. The first two don't differ much apparent from the words on the button. order now and pre-order. Okay I'm going to look at my code and your notes and see if that works for me

Comment: are you getting any divs id="gray" when you inspect element?